# Android BottomNavigationView change icon focus color to accurately indicate fragment in view

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

In my Android app (Java) I'm trying to figure out how to change my icon focus color to accurately indicate the fragment that is visible. If I press on a bottom nav icon, the icon I pressed is in focus and the navigation takes me to the fragment associated with that icon.

However, when I press the back arrow to go back to the home screen, the icon I previously pressed is still in focus instead of the home icon. How can I only have the icon associated with the visible fragment be in focus?

EDIT:

Here's my NavigationActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".activity.NavigationActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="98dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backArrow"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        style="@style/BottomNavTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:theme="@style/app_theme"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_nav" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nav icon color selector xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:color="#8E8392" />
</selector>
```

NavigationActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class NavigationActivity extends DeviceBaseActivity {
    NavController navController;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

    private ActivityNavigationBinding navigationBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        navigationBinding = ActivityNavigationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = navigationBinding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(NavigationActivity.this, R.id.fragment);

        appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();

        setupActionBar(navController, appBarConfiguration);
        

        navigationBinding.bottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.mainFragment:
                        navController.navigate(R.id.mainFragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.scheduleFragment:
                        navController.navigate(R.id.scheduleFragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.settingsFragment:
                        navController.navigate(R.id.settingsFragment);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    


    private void setupActionBar(NavController navController,
                                AppBarConfiguration appBarConfig) {

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfig);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment), appBarConfiguration);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide of code of how you set up your `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: Of course, code has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to `setOnItemSelectedListener`, following is my setup:

**1. Setup Menu Resource File**

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"      //must match the id on navigation graph!!
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/meFragment"        //must match the id on navigation graph!!
        android:icon="@drawable/person"
        android:title="Me" />

</menu>
```

**2. Setup `BottomNavigationView`**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/main" />
```

**3. Setup MainActivity with `BottomNavigationView`**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    navController = getNavHostFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navController

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationView, navController)        //key part
}
```

Demo: https://youtu.be/PSAbsVZz3Xw